# Enabling or disbaling a field according to value of Yes/No (checkbox) field in sharepoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, sharepoint

I have created a list in sharepoint of the form below: [image]

I want to hide the fields 'Tool' and 'Responsible' when the checkbox for 'RCA Required' is unchecked (or No), otherwise the fields such as 'Tool' and 'Responsible' should be shown. I have tried the following code in script editor of sharepoint:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select[title='RCA Required']").click(function() {
if ($('input[title="RCA Required"]').is(':checked'))
{
$('nobr:contains("Tool")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("Responsible")').closest('tr').show();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("Tool")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("Responsible")').closest('tr').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you also place the html here?

Comment: I am working in sharepoint. I need to place only jquery or javascript for enabling or disabling a field in sharepoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to modify as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[title='RCA Required']").click(function() {
if ($('input[title="RCA Required"]').is(':checked'))
{
$('nobr:contains("Tool")').closest('tr').show();
$('nobr:contains("Responsible")').closest('tr').show();
}
else
{
$('nobr:contains("Tool")').closest('tr').hide();
$('nobr:contains("Responsible")').closest('tr').hide();
}
});
});
</script>
```

As the checkbox is input type control not select:

[image]